# Haskell Wikibook - Generalized Algebraic Data Types Exercise - Maybe and Either

Tags: haskell

There's an exercise on [this page of the Haskell Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT#Extending_the_language) which gets you to work through a scenario using Maybe and Either (presumably to show that it is quite painful for the use case).

The exercise is:

```
data Expr = I Int
        | B Bool           -- boolean constants
        | Add Expr Expr
        | Mul Expr Expr
        | Eq  Expr Expr    -- equality test

eval :: Expr -> Maybe (Either Int Bool)
-- Your implementation here.
```

The first lines of the solution are - I think - straightforward:

```
data Expr = I Int         -- integer constants
          | B Bool        -- boolean constants
          | Add Expr Expr -- add two expressions
          | Mul Expr Expr -- multiply two expressions
          | Eq  Expr Expr -- equality test
          deriving (Show)

eval :: Expr -> Maybe (Either Int Bool)
eval (I n) = Just $ Left n
eval (B b) = Just $ Right b
eval (Add e1 e2) = ...
eval (Mul e1 e2) = ...
eval (Eq e1 e2) = ...
```

But I'm not exactly sure how to define the rest. As an example I guess for `add` I need to unpack the `fromLeft`, `fromJust` of each expression, but I'm not sure how to do this properly (with pattern matching?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with pattern matching and perhaps even the `Maybe` monad.

You could implement the `eval (Add e1 e2)` branch using just pattern matching:

```
eval (Add e1 e2) = case eval e1 of
    Just (Left i1) -> case eval e2 of
        Just (Left i2) -> Just (Left (i1 + i2))
        _ -> Nothing
    _ -> Nothing
```

Pattern matching on a pair is one good way of reducing the amount of nested `case` statements:

```
eval (Add e1 e2) = case (eval e1, eval e2) of
    (Just (Left i1), Just (Left i2)) -> Just (Left (i1 + i2))
    _ -> Nothing
```

Or, you could use the `Maybe` monad as an abstraction over those `case` statements. It will automatically return `Nothing` if any of the pattern matching fails in the `do` block bindings (due to how the `Maybe` monad implements [`fail`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:fail)).

```
eval (Add e1 e2) = do
    Left i1 <- eval e1
    Left i2 <- eval e2
    return (Left (i1 + i2))
```

Comment: Pairs are great for reducing the complexity of pattern matching.  The first block above could be rewritten as `case (eval e1, eval e2) of { (Just (Left i1), Just (Left i2)) -> Just (Left (i1 + i2)); _ -> Nothing }`

Comment: @ChrisSmith Nice! I added that

Answer (score 1):

> eval (Add e1 e2) = ...

You will want to evaluate `e1` and `e2` then pattern match on those results. There's various ways of doing that. For instance you can use `let` bindings.

```
let ev1 = eval e1
    ev2 = eval e2 
in
```

And then pattern match using the `case` construction. Or with no `let` bindings if you prefer, you can just do

```
case (eval e1, eval e2) of
```

and pattern match on that pair.